# What is the Meaning of the Icons in Edit Attribute Set Page

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

In this screen snip we're looking at the Edit Attribute Set for the Default Attribute Set. What do these images/icons mean.
[image: Edit Attribute Set]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons with the "restricted" sign (red circle with a white line) are system attributes. They are created by magento and have special meaning. They cannot be removed.
You can do what ever you want with the rest of the attributes.

Comment: Thank you. A fresh install of Magento had "cost" and I think also "manufacturer" with the non-system icon. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: @tzvi, because they don't have special meaning. Those attributes are not referenced in the code and are not required for the application to run properly.